# MySQL 8 is not indexing on Functional index

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-8.0

I'm using MySQL 8.0.30 and known that it's supporting for Functional index. However I tried to create an index base on sum of some fields, it's very easy as below, but index is not used, even in possible indexes, it's not showed as well.

Here is my table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `sample_product` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avai_qty` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `picked_qty` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `functional_index` (((`avai_qty` + `picked_qty`)))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

And here is my query

```sql
select * from sample_product where avai_qty + picked_qty > 5000;
```

I tried to run explain

```json
{
    "query_block": {
        "cost_info": {
            "query_cost": "0.35"
        },
        "select_id": 1,
        "table": {
            "access_type": "ALL",
            "attached_condition": "((`sample_product`.`avai_qty` + `sample_product`.`picked_qty`) > 5000)",
            "cost_info": {
                "data_read_per_join": "1K",
                "eval_cost": "0.10",
                "prefix_cost": "0.35",
                "read_cost": "0.25"
            },
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 1,
            "table_name": "sample_product",
            "used_columns": [
                "id",
                "name",
                "avai_qty",
                "picked_qty"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's MySQL's bug or I did something wrong.

I have tried to show index and here is result, it has functional index as I defined
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to test with a table of a meaningful size? No sane optimizer will choose _any_ index when accessing a one-row table.

Comment: Get a thousand rows in the table.  Change the 5000 to something that will match only a few percent of the table.  Then it might decide that the index is worth using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I changed type of 2 number columns to bigint instead of double, and try again that query, it worked as expected.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `sample_product_bigint` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avai_qty` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `picked_qty` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `functional_index` (((`avai_qty` + `picked_qty`)))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

```sql
explain select * from sample_product_bigint where avai_qty + picked_qty > 5000;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sample_product_bigint |  | range | functional_index | functional_index | 9 |  | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will not use index when the table is almost empty.

MySQL cannot use expressional index when this expression is used in the condition, even when the expression in the index and in the condition matches literally.

Possible solution: create virtual generated column using needed expression, create index by this column, use this column in the condition instead of the expression. Make this column invisible - if not then the queries which are columnslist-critical (for example, `INSERT INTO table SELECT ..`) will fail after new column creation.

```
CREATE TABLE `sample_product` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avai_qty` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `picked_qty` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `functional_index` (((`avai_qty` + `picked_qty`)))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

```
INSERT INTO sample_product
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT 1 id UNION ALL
  SELECT id+1 FROM cte LIMIT 1000
)
SELECT id, '', RAND() * 3000, RAND() * 3000
FROM cte;
```

```
EXPLAIN
select * from sample_product where (avai_qty + picked_qty) > 5000;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sample_product | *null* | ALL | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1000 | 100.00 | Using where |

```
ALTER TABLE sample_product
  DROP INDEX functional_index,
  ADD COLUMN sum_qty DOUBLE AS (`avai_qty` + `picked_qty`) VIRTUAL INVISIBLE,
  ADD INDEX functional_index (sum_qty);
ANALYZE TABLE sample_product;
```

```
EXPLAIN
select * from sample_product where sum_qty > 5000;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sample_product | *null* | range | functional_index | functional_index | 9 | *null* | 60 | 100.00 | Using where |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WBvz9Hlc)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but add a virtual column will change database schema, also code logic need to be changed as well (add a new field to map that virtual column). I just want to add an index to improve performance for existing query, without any code change.